# Disconnect particular wifi in android

Tags: android-layout

how to disconnect a particular wifi in android and then making the device to stop scanning.
i am using disconnect() method but that's not working.
is there any way to stop scanning for further more access points.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to disableNetwork() method of wifiManager class..

Comment: i cant understand what u want to do exactly plz clear the issue so that i can able to answer u.

Comment: actually when i am using disconnect method for a particular access point it keeps on scanning and disabling the wifi...so i want this scanning to stop for once.